# Font Changing to Inherited Font on Screensize Change

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a simple site mobile responsive using "@media only screen", but one of my titles is reverting to an inherited font rather than continuing to use the CSS defined font.

```
//HTML
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="squirrelcss.css"  type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h4> Short Title </h4>
</body>

//CSS
[class*="h4"]{
font-size: 5vw;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
h4{
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
font-size: 2vw;
color:#474644;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;}}
```

On Inspect mode in Google Chrome, it indicates that upon a smaller screen size, h4 is inheriting it's font from it's container element, col-8.

```
.col-8{
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Every other element on the site is correctly changing when the screen size is lowered below the defined 800px, including other text, and I've repeatedly cleared my cache throughout the process to no avail. !important seems to have no effect either.

What can I do to cause the h4 element to keep displaying the 'Pacifico' font instead of the inherited font?

Comment: Could you not simply just add an '! important' to it?

Comment: !important doesn't seem to affect it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What can I do to cause the h4 element to keep displaying the 'Pacifico' font instead of the inherited font?**

Just set `font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;` to your h4 element outside of the @media statement. This way no matter the size of your page, Pacifico (as long as it has loaded) will be the font.

//HTML

```
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="squirrelcss.css"  type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="col-8">
    <h4> Short Title </h4>
    </div>
    </body>
```

//CSS

```
 h4{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    }

    .col-8{
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
    h4{
    font-size: 2vw;
    color:#474644;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;}}
```